# Moved project in Intellij and now I can't compile

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I am working on a project in Intellij. I started working on it offline and then created a repo where I moved my project in.

The problem I'm having now is that the *.idea* folder is no longer generated with all the proper files. Also if I add all of the files back to the *.idea* I am Intellij says that `package does not exist` for all of the libraries defined in the *Maven* *pom* file.

I did not do a **refactor -> move** inside Intellij but instead just moved the folders manually.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reimport the project from existing sources.
`File -> New Project -> Project from existing sources.`
Intellij will recreate all necessary files.

If this is not enough, remove every single intellij file + .idea folder. Keep only src files and pom.xml. Then Reimport maven project again as described above.

Comment: I tried this and it added several configurations where in one I can't find the Main class. If I use another it runs like it's supposed to even though most of the imports are red.

Comment: Go for `File -> Invalidate caches and restart`